# Sharepoint Timer Job succeeded but didn't execute the code

Tags: sharepoint, timer-jobs

I have a custom Timer Job created in Sharepoint 2010. After it runs, the Status shows "succeeded", but it actually doesn't execute the code.

I have managed to debug it, and I saw that it enters in the "empty" constructor several times:

```
public MyTimerJob() : base(){}
```

and then it stops, without entering in the constructor with the parameters:

```
 public MyTimerJob(string name, SPWebApplication webApp,SPServer server, SPJobLockType lockType)
          : base(name, webApp, server, lockType) { }
```

and avoiding the Exectute method:

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
{
  mycode();
}
```

Any suggestions?

I have already

- restarted the SharePoint Timer Service from the Service Tool
- restarted SPTimerV4 from the console
- checked the Application Pool
- killed the OWSTIMER.EXE
- checked the rights of the user which is running the Timer Job
- tried to deactivate/activate the feature

Comment: Could you add code with FeatureActivated and FeatureDeactivating logic? Maybe there is some issue there? Here is the msdn support article for this implementation -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh528518(v%3Doffice.14)
Please compare, maybe there is some small error there.

Comment: Hi Adam! Thanks for your answer, I have solved the issue with the feature, but I still have the TimerJob code not executing..so unfortunately it wasn't related :(